# wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1) when i include "Rails.application.routes.url_helpers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have written application_helper.rb, which is basically global helpers for my Rails application. And in order for me to use url helper like `post_url(post)`, Rails force me to include this code at the top of my application_helper.rb:

`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

I included that line of code like this:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

module ApplicationHelper
....
end
```

And suddenly, when i load my app in the browser, all the `link_to` codes seem to be throwing the same kind of error like this:

`wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)`

Here is the screenshot of that error:

[image]

This is the sample of one my `link_to` code:

```
  <%= link_to root_path do %>
    <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/xxx/xxx-logo-small.png" class="" />
  <% end %>
```

And its not only this link that is causing an error, but all links in my app! So whats wrong with this `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` ? Why is this causing such error? And how could I use this and fix the problem it's causing at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: Try including them INSIDE your helper module, not above it.

Comment: Never heard of Rails to force someone to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to be able to use Rails helpers in your `Helper` modules. How exactly does it forces you?

Comment: @Raffael i've tried that. But then, I also has a rake file that depending on this application_helper. And when I put them INSIDE and try to run my rake file, i got an error. So thats why I put them OUTSIDE. But again, when i put them outside, i got the error like you see on this thread

Comment: @jibiel ah Rails doesn't really force me..It just gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

Do you need add also this includes in your helpers

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
include AbstractController::Helpers
include AbstractController::Translation
include AbstractController::AssetPaths
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```